# Ubuntu, specify interface for a single destination ip

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, routing

On Ubuntu, I have two interfaces `eth0` (`192.168.0.X`) and `wlan0` (`192.168.1.X`) both in DHCP with a gateway and internet.

How can I configure the system for using `eth0` for all the trafic except one public ip adress routed on `wlan0` by default ?

For example :

- `eth0` > all the trafic
- `wlan` > just the trafic to `8.8.8.8`

I got some responses using iptables but not involving destination whitelist like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple scenario. You need to have two things:

- Default gateway via `eth0`. Next hop will be `192.168.0.Y`.
- Static route for single host `8.8.8.8` via `wlan0`. Next hop will be `192.168.1.Y`.

No need to add any rule using iptables.

You can add the default route and static route using these two commands respectively:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.Y
ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 via 192.168.1.Y
```